# Pandas: How to select values from this month and the last two months?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe of multi-year financial budgeting data with the following columns and no NaNs:

```
Index
Dates (datetime) with data for each day of the month
Category (object) with several different names
Amount (float) in USD
```

How would I declare a "this month" value and then filter the dataframe for all values that fall between "this month" and "last month" or "two months" ago?

Comment: could you please share codes so that we can replicate what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use method .today() from [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module to get an actual timestamp and then apply .month to extract month as 'int'. Also you can use .month for filtering like that:

```
import datetime as dt

this_month = dt.datetime.today().month
two_months_ago = this_month - 2 if this_month - 2 > 0 else this_month - 2 + 12
filter = df['Dates'].dt.month == two_month_ago
```

Comment: Thanks, @kasper. But the df['Dates'] column is datetime64[ns] and everything you recommended is an integer. When I try: df2 = df[(df['Date'] >= two_months_ago) & (df['Date'] <= this_month)], I expectedly get: "TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int"

Comment: Try using .dt.month in filter which results in integer too. In case of your example: df2 = df[(df['Date'].dt.month >= two_months_ago) & (df['Date'].dt.month <= this_month)]

Comment: That sort of works, but the problem is that if I run the code today (Jan 23), then it only includes data last month up to December 23 and two months ago up to November 23. Even though I am accessing the data with integer 12 and 11 for month, it takes into consideration the day. Very confused how to avoid that!

Comment: Realized the error occurs when I convert the date column to datetime, but do not know how to fix it: df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [resample method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

```
import pandas as pd
# Use 'ME' for resampling data by month
for month, month_df in df.resample('ME'):
    print(f"Month: {month}")
    print(month_df)
```